# Performing Checkbox operations on a page where I cannot access model files

Tags: javascript, php, html

I do not have access to the models file because the software is encrypted. Currently my Checkboxes are running with Ajax inside a PHP query. Since it works with Ajax, I cannot perform any action with the URL. I want to fetch URL Parameters and only go to the data of those parameters, but I can't. Could you help ?

**My Codes on the category page**

```
    <?php if ($urun_markalar) { ?>
                    <div class="widget cz-filter mb-4 pb-4 border-bottom">
                        <h3 class="widget-title">Markalar</h3>
                        <div class="input-group-overlay input-group-sm mb-2">
                            <input class="cz-filter-search form-control form-control-sm appended-form-control" type="text" placeholder="Arama Yap">
                            <div class="input-group-append-overlay"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="czi-search"></i></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="widget-list cz-filter-list list-unstyled pt-1" style="max-height: 12rem;" data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
                            <?php 
                            $i=0; foreach ($markalar as $marka) { $i++;
                                foreach ($urun_markalar as $key ) { 
                                    if ($marka->marka_id==$key) { ?>
                                        <li class="cz-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input class="custom-control-input common_selector marka" type="checkbox" id="marka_<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $marka->marka_id ?>">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="marka_<?=$i?>"><?php echo $marka->marka_ad; ?></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

An example of the parameter I want to perform

```
https://example.com/kategori/agiz-dis/agiz-calkalama-sulari?id=marka_32
```

In short, when I click on a checkbox from here, I want to see its URL address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the id of the element (or you can loop through the class of checkbox).
add onChange handler, and do whatever you want.

```
$('#marka_1').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
    const markaId = $(this).val();
});
```

'marka_1' is the example of id checkbox, you can use class.

Comment: Hello there,
Thank you for your help answer but unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

Comment: @avztemeleq you can try loop through all checkboxes, then add onChange handler in side that. `$('.marka input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { // here $(this).change(function() { .. }) })` and get the value from onchange.

Comment: I don't think I can do this in full code form, because I'm not good with javascript :)